# Django: render chapter and section headings along with related objects?

Tags: django, django-models

I am setting up a Django database to hold entries for organisms in a book that is organised by chapter, section and subsection. Each chapter has sections, and these sections `may` have subsections. Organisms can belong to *either* a section or a subsection, and are ordered within them.

The data is supplied to me simply as a list of organisms and codes. For example, `Monkeys & apes` has a code field of `01010102`, which means that it is in chapter 1, section 1, and sub-section 1. `Gynandria` has a code field of `02010001`, which means that it is in chapter 2, section 1.

And alongside this I have a text list of chapter and section headings, like `1.1: Mammals` and `1.1.1: Primates`.

There are about 4,000 organisms, and a few hundred sections.

I want to render a template with chapters and section headings in order, and related entries listed below, like this:

> **Chapter 1: Animals**
>    ***Section 1.1: Mammals*** 
>     *Subsection 1.1.1: Primates* 
>     Humans, monkeys & apes...
>  
>    *Subsection 1.1.2: Bruta*
>    Elephants, manatees...
>    ***Section 1.2 Birds***
>     *Subsection 1.2.1: Vultures & condors*
>     Andean condor, king vulture...
>   **Chapter 2: Plants**
>    ***Section 2.1 Monandria***
>    Gynandria,...

My question is: what is a clear and efficient way to do this? I'd like to stay fairly lightweight, while making the models easy to understand. But this page is going to get used a lot, so I'd also like it to be fairly efficient.

I have started by setting up the models as follows:

```
def Section(models.Model):
    chapter = models.IntegerField()
    section = models.IntegerField()
    subsection = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def Organism(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    code = models.IntegerField()
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
```

I was planning to set up my view like this:

```
def all_sections(request):
   sections = Section.objects.all().order_by('-chapter', '-section', '-subsection')
   organisms = Organism.objects.all().order_by('code')
   context = {
      'sections': sections,
      'organisms': organisms
   }
   return render(request, 'all_sections.html', context)
```

And template as follows:

```
{% for s in sections %}
  {% if s.subsection %}
    <h3>{{ s.name }}</h3>
  {% else %}
    {% if s.section %}
      <h2>{{ s.name }}</h2>
    {% else %}
      {% if s.chapter %}
        <h1>{{ s.name }}</h1>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
// Render organisms per section here - but how to do this efficiently?
{% endfor %}
```

I'd appreciate any advice on the clearest, most efficient way to do this. Currently I'm thinking that I could divide up the organisms client-side in JavaScript, but it'd be nice to have a non-JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would make models for Chapter and Subsection, and within the view build the structure, so serverside. The view would just get everything from all Models, without `select_related`, you will have to do this yourself. (I removed the sorts, and try/excepts around castings, you can add them yourself.)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def all_sections(request):
    chapters = dict((c.id, c) for c in Chapter.objects.all().iterator())
    sections = dict((s.id, s) for s in Section.objects.all().iterator())
    subsections = dict((s.id, s) for s Subsection.objects.all().iterator())

    structure = OrderedDict()
    for organism in Organism.objects.all().iterator():
        chapter_id = int(organisme[:2])
        section_id = int(organisme[2:4])
        subsection_id = int(organisme[4:6])

        if chapter_id not in structure:
            structure[chapter_id] = {
                "chapter": chapters[chapter_id],
                "sections": OrderedDict()}

        tmp_sections = structure[chapter_id]["sections"]
        if section_id not in tmp_sections:
             tmp_sections[section_id] = {
                 "section": sections[section_id],
                 "subsections": OrderedDict(),
                 "organisms": []}

        if not subsection_id:  # check if is zero
            tmp_section[section_id]["organisms"].append(organism)
            continue
        else:
            tmp_subsections = tmp_sections["subsections"]
            if subsection_id not in tmp_subsections:
                tmp_subsections[subsection_id] = {
                    "subsection": subsections[subsection_id],
                    "organisms": []}

            tmp_subsections[subsection_id]["organisms"].append(organism)

    return render(request, 'all_sections.html', structure)
```

Not gonna write out the template, think it is pretty simple from here.

PS. If you wanna keep the current Section model, you can do the prefetch as follows:

```
chapters, sections, subsections = dict(), dict(), dict()
for section in Section.objects.all().iterator():
    if section.chapter:
        chapters[section.chapter] = section
    elif section.section:
        sections[section.section] = section
    else:
        subsections[section.subsection] = section
```